# Более релевантный пример для страницы «Тур»

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, справка, новые-участники, тур

На [странице «Тур»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) в качестве примера используется вопрос про защиту маргариток от пони. Мне кажется, этот пример не очень хорошо иллюстрирует систему работы Stack Exchange, да и к тематике Ru.SO не относится. А еще в нем недостаточно <s>тонкой иронии и искрометного юмора</s> <s>лулзов</s> интриги.

Хочу Тур, в котором будет:

1. Наглядный пример,
2. По теме Ru.SO,
3. Интересно узнать ответ.

В качестве ответов предлагайте текст вопроса, желательно с примером ответа. Сделаю отдельный «вопрос отпущения», чтобы голосовать против предложения.

**Почему пони и маргаритки — плохо:**

- Это просто перевод шаблонного текста, который создается на свежем сайте сети SE. Так задумано, что его на что-то заменят.
- Не входит в тематику сайта. На всех крупных сайтах сети используются примеры, входящие в тематику (т.к. там вместо шаблона поставили реальный вопрос).
- Не дает представления о том, какими должны быть вопросы и ответы на сайте.
- Намек на мультяшность и игрушечность. Как будто я читаю сайт для телепузиков, а не для программистов.

Comment: Все это (образцы вопросов-ответов) длинно и  малоинформативно.

Comment: @avp предложите лаконичный вариант)

Comment: Не могу, т.к. сама концепция -- `Вопрос — ответ. Ничего лишнего. ` мне не нравится. / Заодно уж еще раз скажу о метках (тэгах). Когда в процессе прохождения тура человек видит, что есть **80 страниц!!!** разных тэгов, то у него сразу возникает мысль, что метки это просто баловство какое-то, фигня, которая на самом деле не нужна. Отсюда и подход к их выбору в реальных вопросах. Типа -- "Эээ, они вам правда нужны? Пожалуйста, наставлю чего-нибудь, чтобы только не цеплялись..."

Comment: @avp: пример с Бэббиджем как раз иллюстрирует проблему с закрытием хороших, но достаточно широких вопросов.

Comment: И в чем мораль с Бэббиджем (в смысле Тура по ru.SO)? Такие вопросы стоит задавать или нет? А отвечать на них?

Comment: @avp: думаю, что если переформулировать вопрос и ответ, то получится вполне даже хорошо. Текущий вариант существует скорее как самоирония, но если он победит, то напишем хорошую, верную формулировку.

Comment: Если переформулировать под "хорошую, верную формулировку", то весь шарм пропадет.

Answer (score 10):

#### Вычислительная машина

Разработал проект универсальной цифровой вычислительной машины. Есть затруднения с написанием программы hello world.

Чарльз Бэббидж.

> **закрыт** про причине не по теме пользователями Николай Лобачевский, Михаил Остроградский, Исаак Ньютон, Франсуа Виет, Архимед ♦ 20 апр 1833 г. в 10:50
>
> Похоже, этот вопрос не соответствует тематике. Те, кто, голосовал за его закрытие, указывали следующую причину:
>
> - "**Вопросы-опросники запрещены на Stack Overflow на русском**. Для получения ответа, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ." –  Николай Лобачевский, Михаил Остроградский, Исаак Ньютон, Франсуа Виет, Архимед ♦
>
> <sub>Если этот вопрос можно переформулировать согласно правилам, изложенными в Справке, отредактируйте его.</sub>

---

Создала описание и написала hello world для вашей машины.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ада Лавлейс.

---

<sub>Ада, опять вы за новичков домашнюю работу делаете? — Готфрид Лейбниц</sub> 
<sub>@Готфрид да ладно вам, хороший же код — Пифагор ♦</sub> 
<sub>+1, реализация очень интересная — Алан Тьюринг</sub>

Answer (score 3):

#### [Hello world с пустой функцией main](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811/)

Столкнулся с такой задачей на собеседовании: написать программу, которая печатает в консоли фразу "Hello world" при условии, что функция `main()` данной программы выглядит следующим образом:

```
int main(void) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

[c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

Answer (score 1):

Ничего менять не надо, Тур прекрасен в существующем состоянии.

#### Как можно защитить маргаритки от пони?

Мне нравятся пони, которые пасутся под окнами моей кухни, но они съедают практически все маргаритки. Что мне с этим делать?

[пони](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8)[маргаритки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Для справки: это буквальный перевод [страницы «Тур» на StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/tour), только вместо единорогов почему-то появились пони.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Как мне пропатчить KDE2 под FreeBSD?](http://bash.im/quote/42)

[аниме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5)

Comment: Как там в 2000ых?

Comment: @igumnov: зашибенно, доллар по 25.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Что значит "use strict"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435546/181472)

Нередко встречается код со строкой `"use strict";`. Например, библиотеки часто начинаются с этого:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
```

Что значит `"use strict"`, и зачем его использовать?

Answer (score 0):

#### [Двойное отрицание](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/188946/181472)

Как понимать двойное отрицание: `!!` (например, в JavaScript)?